GitHub Contribution Streak Not Updating Despite Proper Commits
I recently committed code to a repository, and while the commit shows up in the repository's commit history, my contribution streak on the GitHub contribution graph is not updating. Here's the detailed breakdown of the situation:
enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/ZLJ5Pu5m.png)
What I’ve Verified:
My Git configuration is correct, and the commit email matches the one linked to my GitHub account.
The repository is public (or I’ve enabled private contributions in my GitHub settings).
The commits are pushed to the default branch (e.g., main or master).
I’ve checked for time zone differences (GitHub uses UTC, and my commits were made accordingly).
The contribution graph has had sufficient time (more than 24 hours) to update.
The repository is not a fork or, if it is, my changes are significant and directly committed (not just merged).
What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it? Is there something I might have overlooked?
enter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
